# trouble finding file in c++ via ifstream

Tags: c++

i have tried this program 5 times but still it is not able to find my file which i have provided path for.basically how do i specify file path

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("C:\\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C++ Project\y.txt");
    char a[20];
    if (!infile)
        cout<<"file doesnt exists";
    else
        while (infile.getline(a, 20, '/n'))
        {
            cout << a;
        }
    _getche();
}
```

Comment: Try escaping tye rest of the `\ ` like you did the first one (`\\ `)

Comment: You seem to have stopped using escaped backslashes after the first... Alternatively, forward slashes work fine as well and do not need to be escaped.

Comment: `\\\` is the reason I switched to Linux and never looked back.

Comment: In C++11 and later, you can use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to avoid having to escape the slashes: `ifstream infile(R"(C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C++ Project\y.txt)");`

Comment: While we're at it, shouldn't `infile.getline(a, 20, '/n')` be `infile.getline(a, 20, '\n')`?

Comment: @PaulSanders yes, or simpler `infile.getline(a, 20)` since `'\n'` is the default delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

> basically how do i specify file path

You have to escape all the backslashes appearing in the file path, not only the first one:

```
ifstream infile("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Templates\\ProjectTemplates\\Visual C++ Project\\y.txt");
                       // ^     ^          ^                   ^  ...
```

Another way is to use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
ifstream infile(R"(C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C++ Project\y.txt)");
```